# Highcharts: Shared tooltip for heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

Is it possible to create a heatmap with shared tooltips as in this example from the Highcharts demo page:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
        ]
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<!-- Highcharts demo code from https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-x-crosshair/ -->

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Shared tooltip for a heatmap means that there is not a single tooltip for every category rather that there is only one tooltip for every x point which displays the values of all categories.

The option sharedTooltip is not available for heatmaps. So is there another way to get shared tooltips for heatmaps in Highcharts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you have noticed the **tooltip.shared** feature is not implemented in the heatmap series. However, you should be able to display all values per category by using the **tooltip.formatter** callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yzxenqfa/

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var series = this.series,
        output = '<b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'x') + '</b> sold <br><b>';
      series.points.forEach(p => {
        if (p.x === this.point.x) {
          output += '<br>' +
            p.value + '</b> items on<b> ' + getPointCategoryName(p, 'y') + '</b>'
        }
      })
      return output
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

---

I am aware that the whole column is not highlighted - this would disturb the colorAxis readability.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be an easy solution.